# How set image on click radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this code:

```
function setImg(id,value){
  jQuery(".mini_img").click(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    jQuery(".catch").attr('src', src);
  });
}
```

This function sets an image in the HTML:

```
function setAttrValue(id, value){
  attr_value[id] = value;
  reloadAttribSelectAndPrice(id);
  reloadAttribImg(id, value);
  setImg(id,value);
}

function reloadAttribImg(id, value){
  var path = "";
  var img = "";
  if (value=="0"){
    img = "";
  }else{
    if (attr_img[value]){
      img = attr_img[value];
    }else{
      img = "";
    }
  }

  if (img==""){
    path = liveimgpath;
    img = "blank.gif";
  }else{
    path = liveattrpath;
  }
  jQuery("#prod_attr_img_"+id).attr('src', path+"/"+img);
}
```

This is the part I do not understand:

```
function reloadAttrValue(){
  for(var id in attr_value){
    if (jQuery("input[name=jshop_attr_id\\["+id+"\\]]").attr("type")=="radio"){
      attr_value[id] = jQuery("input[name=jshop_attr_id\\["+id+"\\]]:checked").val();
    }else{
      attr_value[id] = jQuery("#jshop_attr_id"+id).val();
    }
  }
}
```

I want set image with class `.mini_img` in image with attr, how?
And I can't give `id`, `value` in PHP.

Comment: can you provide your html code

Comment: And the complete relevant code... What you posted is incomplete.